# Nissan Tiida hatchback how to put back water hose of back window's glass

Tags: nissan, hose, rear, washers

I have next issue: a hose of the rear window washer fell off and I have no idea how to put it back. I tried just shove it back by force but without result. Looks like it has a clever way to put the hose back to the connector.

Have anybody idea?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

You can get some “softer” silicon pipe that bends easier and use a straight connector.

One trick is to remove the jet and as you push it back into the hole , you push it into the pipe at the same time - this gives effectively more space to work...

Comment: I don't think the "getting it into the hole" is the issue. It appears to me, the problem stems from the angled portion on the hose not *staying* in the connector. I'll bet this will require replacement of the connector.